# botão compartilhar facebook com link dinâmico

Tags: php, facebook

Bom dia, ja tentei vários scripts para fazer com que meu link dinâmico seja compartilhado com o botão customizado do facebook. Não consigo
Estou tentando isto:

```
<?php $linkFace = "http://www.modalle.com.br/blog.php?artigo=".$_GET['artigo'];?>
<a onClick="return goodPopup(this.href)" href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($linkFace)?>&amp;t=<?php echo urlencode($row['chamada']);?>" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a>
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você pode colocar a sua função goodPopup, e o resultado final do seu href pro pessoal te ajudar melhor?

Comment: <script>
 function goodPopup(url) {
 window.open(url, '_blank', 'scrollbars,resizable,height=400,width=550');
 return false;
 }
</script>

Comment: Vinicius, da um console.log nessa `url` e coloca o que tá vindo aqui pra gente...

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto

```
<?php
   $linkFace = "http://www.modalle.com.br/blog.php?artigo=".$_GET['artigo'];?>
?>

<a href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($linkFace)?>" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a>
```

Adicionar a sugestão comentada pelo colega [vinicius-sanchez-dos-santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64480/vinicius-sanchez-dos-santos) , também funciona